# sql server compiling everything

Tags: sql, sql-server

My sql server is compilng every procedure, the sql server dont care if have some syntax error or not, it's compile, but the intellisense work well
Example, look the comment at last INNER JOIN

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Sky-Disparador-Many-Select-GetUsersInMailing] --22,1--ORA_P7FE_1DP7_A_24NOV16_10,3236
    @dateD INT
    , @contactMedia INT
AS
SELECT customer.cpfCnpj [cpf]
    , contact.Contact [contato]
    , customer.pk_CustomerId [contrato]
    , arrearsStep.Discoun t [PercentualDesconto]
    , Camp.pk_CampaignId [campaingId]
    , customer.CustomerName [nome]
    , cc.pk_CustomerContextId [CustomerContextId]
    , contact.pk_ContactId [ContactId]
FROM [db_sacapp_customer].[dbo].[Customer] customer
LEFT JOIN [db_sacapp_customer].[dbo].[Contact] contact
    ON contact.fk_CustomerId = customer.pk_CustomerId
INNER JOIN CustomerContext cc
    ON cc.fk_CustomerId = customer.pk_CustomerId
INNER JOIN [db_sacapp_customer].[dbo].[CustomerContext_X_Debt] ccXd
    ON cc.pk_CustomerContextId = ccXd.fk_CustomerContextId
INNER JOIN Debt
    ON ccXd.fk_DebtId = pk_DebtId
LEFT JOIN [db_sacapp_customer].[dbo].[Payment] payment
    ON Debt.[pk_DebtId] = payment.[fk_DebtId]
        AND payment.[fk_DebtId] IS NULL
INNER JOIN [db_sacapp_customer].[dbo].[Campaign] Camp
    ON cc.fk_CampaignId = Camp.pk_CampaignId
INNER JOIN [db_sacapp_customer].[dbo].[ActionRule] ACT
    ON ACT.pk_ActionRuleId = Camp.fk_ActionRuleId
INNER JOIN [db_sacapp_customer].[dbo].[ArrearsStep_X_ActionRule] x
    ON x.fk_ActionRuleId = ACT.pk_ActionRuleId
INNER JOIN [db_sacapp_customer].[dbo].[ArrearsStep] arrearsStep
    ON x.fk_ArrearsStepId = arrearsStep.pk_ArreacccxcxcxzfdsafsdfrsStepId --Example: the intellisense work and say this is wrong, but the sql server compile it (Command(s) completed successfully.)
WHERE Debt.D BETWEEN arrearsStep.DStart
        AND arrearsStep.DEnd
            --and customer.pk_CustomerId in (5037281) 
    AND contact.fk_ContactMedia = @contactMedia
```

I already turn off the sql(sql process) and turn on, refresh the DB and a lot of things

Comment: so what you're saying is that SQL Server allows you to compile and create stored procs that have errors in them, when it should stop you and display the errors.

Comment: are you talking about red warnings in intellisense

Comment: Being unable to resolve an object identifier at compile time is not an error ([*deferred name resolution*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.90).aspx)), however `arrearsStep.Discoun t [PercentualDesconto]` is a parse error.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I think he's saying the query executes although Intellisense underlines it with red.

Comment: Yeah I think he is talking about deferred name resolution.

Comment: @Tanner is exactly it

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, object evaluation is not done at compile-time but at run-time. So as long as the syntax is correct you can compile any SQL code, irrespective if the objects that it references exists or not.

What you're saying in your question is that you have "syntax" error, but that is not true. An invalid column name is not related to syntax.

For more information take a look at [Deferred Name Resolution and Compilation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx)